# カレンダーに日時を渡す方法をお教えいただけませんか

Tags: monaca

どなたか Android の **カレンダー** に、タイトル、メモ、開始時間、終了時間を渡す方法をご教授願えないでしょうか？

下記の方法を試してみたのですが、
これだとタイトルとメモは渡すことが出来ましたが、開始時間と終了時間が渡せませんでした。

```
extras:{title:Title,description:Memo,beginTime:(new Date(KaisiJikan).getTime()),endTime:(new Date(SyuuryouJikan).getTime())},
```

なお、時間の取得部分を下記のようにしてみたのですが、やはり時間を渡せません。

```
extras:{title:Title,description:Memo,beginTime:(new Date().getTime()),endTime:(new Date().getTime())},
```

「`beginTime`」「`endTime`」の書き方が違うのかな？と思ったのですが、素人ゆえどこを直せばよいのか分からず困っております。
何かヒントをいただけたら幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

---

### 3/19追記

ご回答頂きありがとうございます。

ご教授いただいた、

- キーを文字列にする方法
- `(new Date().getTime())`を変数にいったん格納する方法

もためしましたが、残念ながらやはり日付データを渡せませんでした。

他に `beginTime:(new Date().getTime())` の書き方などで、注意するべき点はあるでしょうか？
何でも試してみたいと思いますので、どうぞよろしくお願いします。

（一応別の Android 端末(バージョン4.1.1)でも試してみたのですが、やはり同じ結果でした。）

Comment: キーを文字列にしてみてください。
extras:{"title": Title,"description":Memo,"beginTime": (new Date().getTime()), "endTime": (new Date().getTime())}
また、「(new Date().getTime())」を一旦変数に格納してから、extrasで使用してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 早速のご回答を頂きありがとうございます！

お教え頂いたように文字列に変換してみたのですが
（「extras:{"title": Title,"description":Memo,"beginTime": (new Date().getTime()), "endTime": (new Date().getTime())} コピペさせてi頂きました）
変化はありませんでした。やはりメモとタイトルのみ渡せましたが、日時を渡せません。

また、変数に
var TIMED = new Date().getTime();
としてから
extras:{"title": Title,"description":Memo,"beginTime": TIMED, "endTime": TIMED } 
ともしてみたのですが、やはり同じで、日時データを渡すことができません。

カレンダー予定追加画面で表示されるのはデフォルトのまま、開始日時は「現在時刻」・終了日時は「現在時刻+1時間」となっています。


＊今思いついたのですが
（実機でのテストをひとつの端末でしかしていないので）端末によって出来ないものもある、という可能性がもしかしたらあるのでしょうか？
明日、もう一台androidを用意して試してみます。

引き続きご教授お願い致します。

Comment: 似たような質問がありましたので、既読かもしれませんが、https://monaca.mobi/ja/forum/q/534361dbfd1734da1d2225a1。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
既読ではありますが、再確認をしてきました。
#7のコードをコピペしてendtimeのみ「extra['endTime'] = new Date().getTime() + 1100;」にして（終了時刻が一時間後のままだとデフォルト表示どおりなので、動作が確認できないと考え、数字だけ変更してみました）試しました。ですが、これでもダメでした。

そうなるとこのコードではない部分が影響しているのでしょうか。
あるいは日時の受け渡しに必要なプラグインなどがあるのでしょうか？

また引き続きお願いできればありがたいです。

Comment: 上記に記載したフォーラムの#7の回答において、 「window.plugins.webintent.startActivity()」の actionに「android.intent.action.EDIT」が使用されていますが、そこは今回の件に関係していないでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘有有難うございます。日時が渡せないだけでメモとタイトルは渡すことが出来ているので、「android.intent.action.EDIT」はちゃんと動いているのではないかな、と考えています。（いかんせん初心者なもので、理解が間違っていたら教えてください！）